# Receive, Store, Interact with emails rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-client

With my rails application, I'm supposed to provide following features:

1. There a limited number of users interacting with my system (in order of 10 to 20)
2. Like any normal mail client users should be able to have an inbox page showing received message, response to individual email and etc....
3. The mail client part cannot be an external application, they want everything packaged into a single application!
4. Normally These emails should be stored for future use
5. In order to send a receive email, we do not need to setup a mail server. They will provide the server and we will fetch the message with POP3 or something else. Same goes for sending emails.
6. The application itself often needs to look into these message as well, so it should be able to access corresponding email objects.

Separate part of these applications can be handled with individual gems such as Mailman, ActionMailer, and etc...

But what would be your suggestions to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I suggestion customizing an open source solution according to your needs. This is a gem/project that you should look at https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer It has all the features that you mentioned and its straightforward in its customizations.